# Paste as value error 1004

Tags: vba, copy-paste, paste

I'm running a macro to copy and paste. Up until this point it runs like a dream. It looks like this now:

```
WsComp.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy WsCBlad.Range("B2")
```

However, I would like to paste as value. I assumed the code has to look as follows to achieve this:

```
WsComp.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy WsCBlad.Range("B2").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

When I run it, it gives error 1004, Pastespecial class range.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u try the past value in the next line like

```
WsComp.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy 
WsCBlad.Range("B2").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: I agree with splitting the operation into two lines, this will help diagnose which clause is the problem.

Comment: Splitting it did the trick. I hit enter and the (xlpastevalues) automatically skipped a space to the right and that was it.